# Convert firebase data to string variable

Tags: c#, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem with saving data from firebase in string. While i try to display data i saved from list to string i get the

> System Collection Generic List with model instead of the string data

Getting the data from firebase:

```
 public async Task<List<StudentModel>>GetAll()
    {
        return (await firebaseClient.Child(nameof(StudentModel)).OrderByKey().LimitToLast(1).OnceAsync<StudentModel>()).Select(item => new StudentModel
        {

           
            Id = item.Key
            

        }).ToList();
    }
```

Convert and display

```
         var students = await studentRepo.GetAll();
    

        string key = students.ToString();

        await DisplayAlert("a", key, "a");
```

I dont understand why it happens, also if someone knows an easier way to do it i would love to hear it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`studentRepo.GetAll` returns a **`List<StudentModel>`**.  You are trying to turn that in a single string.  Either update your query to return a string, or you can extract just the key value using `students[0].Id`